# Converter String de uma div para int e fazer uma operação matemática

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou tentando fazer a seguinte função:

```
    <span id="our_price_display">R$ 71,90</span>

    function calculaParcela(){
    var regex = /\d+,\d+/g;
    var texto = $(".our_price_display").text(); //id da div com o texto R$ 71,90
    var valor = regex.exec(texto);
    var insereValor = $("#valor-parcelado").text(valor.join(""));

    console.log(insereValor);

    var divide = insereValor / 3;

    console.log(divide); 
}
```

Porém no console ele me Retorna NaN.

em que estou errando e o que poderia ser feito pra corrigir esta operação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NaN é um erro retornado para não numérico (not a number). Você terá que converter pra número usando [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#resultado").text(calculaParcela());
});

function calculaParcela() {
  var regex = /\d+,\d+/g;
  var texto = $("#our_price_display").text(); //id da div com o texto R$ 170
  var valor = regex.exec(texto);
  var insereValor = parseFloat(valor.join("").replace(",","."));
  var divide = insereValor / 3;
  return divide;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="our_price_display">R$ 71,90</span>
<br/>
<span id="resultado"></span>
<br/>
<button>Só valor</button>
```

Comment: Cara, deu certinho! Muito obrigadooo!